# How do I translate this bash function to fish shell?

Tags: bash, function, shell, fish

```
function run () {
    nohup python $1 > nohup.out &
}
```

On the command line I call this as "run scriptname.py" and bash executes the following command:

```
python scriptname.py > nohup.out &
```

Can you help me translate this to fish.

I have this so far..

```
function run 
    bash -c "nohup python $1 > nohup.out &"
end
```

When I call source on ~/.config/fish/config.fish

This exists simply saying

```
Error when reading file: ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

without providing any helpful hints as to what the error is.

Comment: Do you want it translated with all the bugs intact?

Comment: ...and why use `paste` at all? It buys you absolutely nothing of value here. If you wanted to (badly) translate stdin to an argument list, `$(cat)` would do it equivalently.

Comment: ...but see again, *badly*. It won't handle quotes, it won't let you do escaping, it won't let you pass arguments with spaces... it would be better if you described your actual goal and asked for the best way to accomplish it, rather than giving us a buggy code to translate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right, paste is a redherring for this discussing. I removed it. My goal is to have a command run in the background using my scriptname... so prepend nohup and end with & and paste the scriptname inside. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5):

There's really no need to execute `bash` here, fish can also execute `nohup`, the redirections also work and such.

There's a minor difference in that, instead of $1 and $2 and so on, arguments to fish functions are stored in the $argv array.

```
function run
     nohup python $argv > nohup.out &
end
```

This will expand $argv to all elements of that as one element each, so `run script.py banana` would run `nohup python script.py banana > nohup.out &`. If you truly want just one argument to be passed, you'd need `$argv[1]`.

I actually have no idea why your definition should cause an error when sourcing config.fish - which fish version are you using?

Comment: Note that on my system, `nohup` prints an annoying message about stderr being redirected to stdout _on stderr_, but that should also happen when doing the same under bash.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly valid (and more correct) replacement for your function in fish:

```
function run
    bash -c 'nohup python "$@" > nohup.out &' _ $argv
end
```

This is an equivalent to the native-bash function:

```
run() {
  nohup python "$@" </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
}
```

...which, personally, I would suggest rewriting to use `disown` rather than `nohup`.

---

With respect to the error seen from `fish`, I'd suggest paying attention to any other (not syntax-related) which may have impacted whether your file could be read -- permissions, etc.